# MediaPlayer -- maximum count and its influencing factors

Tags: android, media-player, limit

Quoting Glenn Kasten:

"For audio, there's a hard limit of 32 active AudioTrack objects per *device* (not per app: you need to share those 32 with rest of the system), and AudioTrack is used internally beneath SoundPool, ToneGenerator, MediaPlayer, native audio based on OpenSL ES, etc. But the actual AudioTrack limit is < 32; it depends more on soft factors such as memory, CPU load, etc. Also note that the limiter in the Android audio mixer does not currently have dynamic range compression, so it is possible to clip if you have a large number of active sounds and they're all loud."

So, practically, 1 MediaPlayer I use corresponds to 1 AudioTrack from the system.

Important question: released MediaPlayers (i.e. those which got release() from me) do not count, right? I.e. if I have 7 Media Players but 5 from those were already released, I use up only 7-5=2 AudioTracks from the global system pool. Is this correct?

(Therefore, if all applications correctly cared for releasing in their onStop/onPause, then it is difficult to reach the hard limit mentioned above; because only the foreground and possibly some paused apps use up AudioTracks -- except for the OS, of course).

Comment: A MediaPlayer has to play something to have an active audio track and I guess the system will clean up old audio players at some point too because your device would be broken after using a few badly coded apps and you had to reboot.